# ColdFusion BitAnd function for biginteger or 64-bit signed integers

Tags: math, coldfusion, bit-manipulation

I am using ColdFusion `bitAnd` function. This function operates on 32-bit signed integers, in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647. I need to use mathematical operation for 64-bit signed integers, so my range is more than limit.

Is there any other way to do that or any other custom mathematical function is available other than `bitAand()`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you just sue the native Java methods of BigInteger? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#and(java.math.BigInteger)

Comment: Obviously (?) that should say "use", not "sue" ;-)

Comment: (Edit) *use the native Java methods of BigInteger* Yep, since CF does not really support `long`, using BigInteger is probably the best way to go, then grab the [`longValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#longValue()) when done.